# Backup during Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, backup, partitioning

I want to upgrade my ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04. Is it possible and safe to backup my HOME folder in different disk partition in the same system and restore it later, after upgrading my os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade to 14.04. Your `/home` wont be affected in upgrade. If you want to backup your apps then install this Software `Aptik`

Type this in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install aptik`

Just backup your `Installed Packages` & later restore.

Type this in terminal if you do not have in your repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Comment: Thanks @DpN. aptik is not available. Do I need to add repository?

Comment: I have edited my answer with repository path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless you do a fresh install and accidentally overwrite the backup partition. But for an upgrade, it is OK.

Comment: Thanks @Jos. What do you mean by fresh install? Right now I'm using 32 bit 13.10. I want to upgrade to 64 bit 14.04. Is it okay?

Comment: For a fresh install, you would backup your files, then download an .iso file, put that on a USB drive, boot up from it, install Ubuntu 14.04, and wipe your existing Ubuntu drives in the process. An upgrade is a just a question of running Software Updater.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't noticed you want to upgrade to a 64 bit version. That is possible without a complete fresh install, but it is not for the faint-of-heart. Take a deep breath and see [this tutorial](http://users.digitalkingdom.org/~rlpowell/hobbies/debian_arch_up/index.html). A fresh install would be less trouble.